# Play rtmp streaming on silverlight

Tags: silverlight, streaming, rtmp

Hi I have a live streaming with link rtmp://IP/live.

I know this rtmp streaming only play with flash player.
But I want to play this on silverlight or window phone 7 ,Is this possible?